# datetime object from string, seconds in float

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

```
>>> a = "2016-03-22 12:33:45.7565"
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .7565
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .7565
```

I have used `%S` and `%f` but how I can handle seconds if that is type `float`?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The digits after the decimal point are microseconds, and are formatted separately from the seconds:

```
>>> a = "2016-03-22 12:33:45.7565"
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 22, 12, 33, 45, 756500)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just an alternative approach - let the [`dateutil` parser](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) do the job:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> a = "2016-03-22 12:33:45.7565"
>>> parse(a)
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 22, 12, 33, 45, 756500)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [18]: a = "2016-03-22 12:33:45.7565"

In [19]: datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
Out[19]: datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 22, 12, 33, 45, 756500)
```